# loop through datagrid values and use the value for other datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, foreach, datagrid

I have a datagridview and i want to get values of the model column and get the count of the model for the other datagridview but i dont know how to loop through the value of the cells from the first datagrid.

[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bg5B.jpg)

What i want is to make the count datagrid on the right side to have 2 columns also. This is my code:

```
  Private Sub jessy()
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim a = requestDatagridview.Rows.Count
    MsgBox(a)
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In requestDatagridview.Rows
        Label1.Text = row.Cells("model").Value
        conn = New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1; port=3306; username=root; password=""; database= atos_db"

        Dim dbDataset1 As New DataTable
        Dim sda1 As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim bsource1 As New BindingSource
        Try
            conn.Open()
            Dim query As String
            query = "select count(serial_no) as 'Count' from atos_db.equip_tbl left join atos_db.itemdetails_tbl on equip_tbl.itemdetails_id=itemdetails_tbl.itemdetails_id left join atos_db.brand_tbl on itemdetails_tbl.brand_id = brand_tbl.brand_id left join atos_db.item_tbl on brand_tbl.item_id=item_tbl.item_id where model='" & a & "'"

            comm = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)

            sda1.SelectCommand = comm
            sda1.Fill(dbDataset1)
            bsource1.DataSource = dbDataset1
            countDatagridview.DataSource = bsource1
            sda1.Update(dbDataset1)
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Dispose()
        End Try
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to count distinct models or just the number of rows in the datagridview ?

Comment: I want to count the no of equipment of the model frm the first datagrid.

Comment: the total qty of item?

Comment: I actually get the count from the database. The total no. of each model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code may help you :

```
' Create a variable to store your value (example qty)
Dim total As Integer = 0

' Loop through your datagridview rows.
For i As Integer = 0 To dtgv.Rows.Count - 1 
' Add the qty value of the current row to total
total = total + dtgv.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
Next

' Then, modify the value of the second dtgv
dtgv2.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = total
```